# Reverse-engineer a private RESTful API?

Tags: json, api, rest, reverse-engineering

Is there a way to reverse-engineer a private RESTful API?

Say, I have a website that uses this API, and I was able to figure out some access point urls of the API. Now, for those urls I need to figure out which JSON payload it will except. Is there a methodical way to do this?

Comment: Use wireshark and look what the other clients do.

Comment: There are no other clients, there is just a website, which does seem to use the API (at least directly, according to my browser's developer console)

Comment: A REST service without clients and without documentation doesn't make sense IMHO. However you could try trail and error.

Comment: When you say, you were "able to figure out some access point urls of the API," is this a well-known URL that returns you a series of links? I ask because, for some media types, the link relation names returned in a document like that are often URIs which can be dereferenced as a URL to obtain the documentation of that relation. For an example, see: http://haltalk.herokuapp.com

Comment: Well, it was more trial and error, really. The good news was that apparently there is a proprietary iphone app which uses the API. So what I'm goign to do is I'll intercept http requests coming from it using a proxy.

Answer (score 3):

For future reference, some applications to do so are:

- [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) (as suggested by @rekire)
- proxy application such as [BURP Suite](http://portswigger.net/burp/). Have a look at [this tutorial](http://www.tuaw.com/2011/02/21/how-to-inspect-ioss-http-traffic-without-spending-a-dime/) for using BURP with Mac.

Download, if available, an existing client/mobile app for the API you are about to investigate and look at the data the application sends and retrieves.

Comment: How about charles proxy or even fiddler ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use network analyzer tool like **WIRESHARK** to capture data sent on network
Read more about it on [wireshark site](https://www.wireshark.org/)

For example i hit login web service
data captured by wireshark is as:
[image]

In above image you can see data sent on HTTP protocol

**1**.) method **POST**

**2**.) Under **MIME** info
for example

*Content-Disposition: form-data; name="phoneNumber"\r\n\r\n*

name of parameter is **phoneNumber**

**===========UPDATE==============**

Here you can see fiddle captured data:

**1**.) Click on GO bottun, after that it starts capturing requests [image: Fiddle screenshot]

Comment: Great answer! Do you know how you could filter it for mobile requests? (Like from your phone)

Comment: @MaxDoesStuff to trace mobile request you have to be on the same internet connection and the API URL should be HTTP, not HTTPS

Answer (score 2):

I would look into [HTTP Toolkit](https://httptoolkit.tech/). It's a great tool that logs network requests including URLs, headers, body, and more. HTTP Toolkit can be used to view requests coming from a browser, terminal, JVM, Android device, *etc.* It's open source and works on Mac, Linux, and Windows.
[image: HTTP Toolkit sources]
[image: HTTP Toolkit request]

Comment: I started using http tool kit some days ago. And I noticed that the request body and response is encrypted or hashed for some endpoints. Does httptoolkit have a workaround?

Comment: Not that I know of, you will have to figure out what type of algorithm is being used to mask the request and reverse engineer that too.